# MarkLogic Record Loader issues

Tags: multithreading, marklogic

We are using the ML record loader jar for loading records in our MarkLogic database .

We have a wrapper around it but we face an issue of thread going to sleep and never reclaimed .

Following are the details on the issue and our proposed solution. Can you please let us know if there is another way we should be handling job :-

Brief issue:
We have been facing frequent issues with the loading jobs getting hung. Every time this happens job need to re-run and then it completes successfully. Loading jobs handle moving/loading documents from staging directory to ML database. We use RecordLoader for inserting documents to ML database It looks like the thread in thread pool executor within the ML jar goes to sleeping mode for long time and is never reclaimed. 
Proposed solution:
We are currently looking for ways to reclaim the sleeping/idle thread within RecordLoader jar. Based on whatever research we have done around this, setting allowCoreThreadTimeOut() to ‘TRUE’ for thread pool executor might achieve this.

Any expert comments on the above proposed solution. Will it work? Any other options to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [MarkLogic Content Pump](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp), which is developed, maintained, and supported by MarkLogic. The import functionality can load from a file system directory into the MarkLogic database.